# unable to insert data in hive having custom delimiter

Tags: file, hadoop, hive, bigdata, database

I am trying to learn hive, this may be stupid a question but
I created a table in hive as follows

```
create table if not exists tweets_table( 
     tweetdata STRING,
     followerscount INT,
     friendscount INT,
     statuscount INT,
     retweetcount INT,
     favouritescount INT,
     lang STRING,
     placefullname STRING,
     placename STRING,
     countryname STRING,
     countrycode STRING,
     hashtags STRING)
     ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^**^'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD  DATA LOCAL INPATH  '/home/cloudera/Desktop/TestDB.txt' INTO TABLE tweets_table5 ;
```

I have used '^**^' to delimit the text because the tweets has a lot of "\n \r ," (please suggest a standard practice if any)

So I have a text file which I am trying to load

```
09-09-2016 10:51:33|^**^|@ArvindKejriwal @abpnewstv तुम्हारे दावों का क्या हुआ केजरीवाल।|^**^|74|^**^|30|^**^|0|^**^|98|^**^|0|^**^|49|^**^|en|^**^|Ambikapur, India|^**^|Ambikapur|^**^|India|^**^|IN|^**^|[]
09-09-2016 10:51:37|^**^|@LiveLawIndia It is shocking a judge  arrested. I am sure Higher Judiciary will come their rescue , Judges per se cannot be wrong|^**^|0|^**^|14|^**^|0|^**^|32|^**^|0|^**^|2|^**^|en|^**^|Rajasthan, India|^**^|Rajasthan|^**^|India|^**^|IN|^**^|[]
```

After successfully loading it and querying it,
 I  get the following output

```
 09-09-2016 10:51:33|   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    |30|    **  |0| **  |98|    **
 09-09-2016 10:51:37|   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    |14|    **  |0| **  |32|    **
```

I fail to understand where am I going wrong is it in my tex tfile or the hive table. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with what you're trying to do:

Using `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` You can't have a delimiter that is more than 1 char.

Even if that worked, that doesn't solve the problem that your tweets have line delimiters in them - each `\n` in a tweet starts a new row.

The way you describe your table - it's impossible to parse correctly - you can't have `\n` as line delimiters and in the tweet data. If you are the one generating this input file, I would suggest replacing all `\n` and `\r` in the tweets with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Create table with [regex serde](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.html) instead of default hive serde.

Modify below regex based on number of columnns.:

```
^(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)$
```

**Table:**

```
create external table if not exists tweets_table( 
     tweetdata STRING,
     followerscount INT,
     friendscount INT,
     statuscount INT,
     retweetcount INT,
     favouritescount INT,
     lang STRING,
     placefullname STRING,
     placename STRING,
     countryname STRING,
     countrycode STRING,
     hashtags STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = " ^(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)\|\^\*\*\^\|(.+)$",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s %11$s %12$s %13$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**Load data:**

```
LOAD  DATA LOCAL INPATH  '/home/cloudera/Desktop/TestDB.txt' INTO TABLE tweets_table ;
```

If you get `RegexSerDe classNotFoundException` then add regex serde jar:

```
ADD JAR hive-contrib=x.x.x.jar
```

Comment: this regex is exactly what i was looking but,I am getting an error FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 9
 ^(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)|^**^|(.+)$

Comment: Remove output.format.string parameter. Put your file in hdfs and instead of internal table create external table using this regex.